# same collectionview cell using multiple viewcontroller problem

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, viewcontroller

When I try to use the same cell in more than one viewcontroller, I get Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value error when I try to fill in the labels in the cell.

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CategoryCollectionViewCell
        
        cell?.categoryLabel.text = "label"
        
        cell!.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 7.5
        return cell!
    }
```

Comment: Try using a NIB instead

Comment: Any time you say an exclamation mark, you are _asking_ to crash. You can hardly be surprised, then, when you _do_ crash. As for why, it seems mostly like that `cell` is `nil`, which would be because this collection view does not have a prototype cell with an identifier called `"cell"`. It's easy to look and see, on both counts.

Comment: That is the problem. I have prototype cell identifer "cell", in one vc its working but using in multiple vc doesnt work.

Comment: That makes no sense. The same prototype cell cannot belong to "multiple vc".

Comment: No ı mean one vc prototype cell id "cell" other one "categoryCell" they belongs same CollectionViewCell but not work. so it doesn't work when i connect to same CollectionViewCell file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you design a collection view cell as a **prototype** in Storyboard:

[image]

That cell belongs to ***that collection view*** and that collection view only. You cannot use it with other collection views or controllers.

If you want to design a cell that can be used in multiple controllers / collection views, you need to either design it as a XIB or code-only.